# Wordpress - Trying to show user profile images

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the Custom User Profile Photo plugin and I was trying to call the profile images to a loop on the mainpage I am creating. If the user has a post, it should display the post and their profile image. I know I am probably doing something really simple wrong, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out. Right now it will show the same image and name, but the post itself is going to the users posts. Forgive me if it's something stupid. It has been quite a while since I have been in php.

```
<?php
     $posts = get_posts('orderby=author&numberposts=10&category_name=userstories');
    foreach($posts as $post){
 ?>
 <ul class="random_user_stories">
<li>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

        $imgURL = get_the_author_meta('cupp_upload_meta',$author->ID);
        $name = get_the_author_meta('first_name'). ' ' .get_the_author_meta('last_name');
        echo '<img src="'. $imgURL .'" alt=""/><br/>';
        echo "$name's Story";
    ?>
    </a>
</li>
</ul>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: what is coming in $imgURL? means which url ?

Comment: $imgURL is pulling the profile URL. It's pulling the second users profile image and not the first users image.